# images are not displaying in AWS S3 bucket

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I have a deep thoughts application that utilizes DynamoDB and S3. I have set up a POST route to add submitted images to the database. Initially, I successfully stored two images in my S3 bucket: one through Insomnia and the other through the application's browser. However, I'm currently facing two issues:

When I run the command `aws dynamodb scan --table-name Thoughts` to scan for the images in the DynamoDB database, the images are not displayed in the JSON response.

Additionally, the images are not visible within the S3 dashboard.

In summary, I'm experiencing difficulties retrieving the images from DynamoDB and observing them in the S3 dashboard.

This is my route

```
router.post('/users', (req, res) => {
    const params = {
      TableName: table,
      Item: {
        username: req.body.username,
        createdAt: Date.now(),
        thought: req.body.thought,
        image: req.body.image,
      },
    };
```

Put method of the AWS SDK for DynamoDB to save data into a DynamoDB table.

```
dynamodb.put(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(
          'Unable to add item. Error JSON:',
          JSON.stringify(err, null, 2),
        );
        res.status(500).json(err); // an error occurred
      } else {
        console.log('Added item:', JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        res.json({ Added: JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) });
      }
    });
```

Image upload to S3

```
const storage = multer.memoryStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, '');
    },
});

const upload = multer({ storage }).single('image');

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
});

router.post('/image-upload', upload, (req, res) => {
    const params = paramsConfig(req.file);
    s3.upload(params, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.status(500).send(err);
        }
        res.json(data);
    });
});
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough information for anyone to help. You don't show how you save the item in DynamoDB and you having shared that you have received a 200 status code?